# Is it possible to get extra information in a onTap GestureDetector function in flutter

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

flutter is very new to me, so probably flutter experts will view it as a very basic question.
I have a number of Text buttons and when they are pressed I want to handle them with the same function.
But that function must know which button is pressed. It could be an extra paramater, or the function should somehow retrieve the Widget of the pressed button.
The relevant code I tried is shown below. With this code the parameter i in handledigit is always 10.
What is the right way to do this?

```
class MijnWidget extends StatelessWidget
{
     void handledigit(i)
     {
         print(i.toString());
     }

     Widget build(BuildContext context)
     {
         int i;
         Row row;

         List<Widget> footerbuttons;
         String str;
         footerbuttons = new List<Widget>();
         for (i=1; i<= 9; i++)
         {
             str = i.toString();

             footerbuttons.add
             (
                 GestureDetector
                 (
                     child:Text(str),
                     onTap:() {handledigit(i);},
                 )
             );
        }
        row = Row(children: footerbuttons, mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween);

        // Here a MaterialApp with a Scaffold containg row is returned

     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the lambdas passed to `onTap` refer to the same `i` which will 9 at the end of the loop. If you make a new variable within the loop, `final localI = i` and use that in your `onTap` callback, it should work.

Better would be to avoid mutable variables and use something like:

```dart
Row(
  children: List.generate(10, (index) =>
    GestureDetector(
      child: Text("$index"),
      onTap: () => handledigit(index),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Thanks spkersten, both solutions work. I use now the following:
    row = Row(
        children: List.generate(9, (index) =>
            GestureDetector(
               child: Text("${index+1}"),
               onTap: () => handledigit(index + 1),
            ),
        ),
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
     );

Answer (score 0):

The topic is a bit old, but if GestureDetector is in mutable **for**, can also be used as external widget:

```
Widget MyGestureDetector (int i, String str) {
  return GestureDetector
    (
       child:Text(str),
       onTap:() {handledigit(i);},
    )
}

for (i=1; i<= 9; i++) {
  footerbuttons.add(MyGestureDetector(i, i.toString()));
}
```